# How to organize simultaneous operation of Telegram bot (Aiogram) and Flask?

Tags: multithreading, flask, async-await, telegram, aiogram

I need advice.

I have a bot (written using telebot) and an API (Flask) that are running in two threads and quietly working at the same time. The bot is launched via polling.

The API handles incoming POST requests from multiple addresses.

Now I'm rewriting the bot using aiogram.
I know that you can't mix asynchrony and threads, but there are difficulties with the simultaneous operation of these two modules. Either the bot or the API works.

What are the options to make friends with Flask and Aiogram, or should we abandon the use of Flask and process requests in a different way?

I also read about the option with webhooks, it seems that you can catch POST requests there, and then Flask is not needed.

I tried the option of running in different threads:

```
import threading
import time
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask,request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import config
import asyncio,hashlib,requests,threading,time
import logs
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from asyncio import new_event_loop, set_event_loop

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
dp = Dispatcher(Bot(token=config.bot_token))

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def message_start(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("HI")

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def get_test():
    data = request.get_json()
    print (data)
    return ("ok")

def app_run():
    while True:
        try:
            app.run()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)

def bot_polling():
    try:
        executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
        set_event_loop(new_event_loop())
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)

bot_thread = threading.Thread(target=bot_polling)
bot_thread.daemon = True
bot_thread.start()

app_thread = threading.Thread(target=app_run)
app_thread.daemon = True
app_thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        try:
            sleep(1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            break
```

I also tried using asynchrony using "on_startup" built-in aiogram:

```
import threading
import time
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
import config
import asyncio,hashlib,requests,threading,time
import logs
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from asyncio import new_event_loop, set_event_loop

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
dp = Dispatcher(Bot(token=config.bot_token))

@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def message_start(message: types.Message):
    print("hi")
    await message.answer("HI")

@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def get_test():
    data = request.get_json()
    print (data)
    return ("ok")

async def is_enabled():
  while True:
    await app.run()

async def on_startup(x):
    asyncio.create_task(is_enabled())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher=dp, skip_updates=True, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for you is https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/webhook_example.html webhooks.

If you take out the logic of working with the database in a separate module with which we will communicate with the flask and the bot, there should be no problems. And then just run them with such a crutch :)

Two modules working in parallel:

`flask_api.py`

```
def main():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    api = Api(app)
    api.init_app(app)
    app.run(port=PORT, host=HOST)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

`aiogram_bot.py`

```
async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=TOKEN_TG)
    dp = Dispatcher(bot)
    
    await dp.skip_updates()
    await dp.start_polling()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

And I run them like this:

`app.py`

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess


api_process = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=subprocess.run,
    kwargs={
        'args': f'{PYTHON_PATH} flask_api.py',
        'shell': True
    })


bot_process = multiprocessing.Process(
    target=subprocess.run,
    kwargs={
        'args': f'{PYTHON_PATH} aiogram_bot.py',
        'shell': True
    })


if __name__ == '__main__':
    api_process.start()
    bot_process.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its quite late but i fixed it like this:

```
import asyncio

async def start_raid_bot():
    dp_bot1 = Dispatcher()
    dp_bot1.include_router(raid_router)
    await dp_bot1.start_polling(bot1)

async def start_trend_bot():
    dp_bot2 = Dispatcher()
    dp_bot2.include_router(router_trend_bot)
    await dp_bot2.start_polling(bot2)

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(confirm_payment_and_inform_user())
    task_bot1 = asyncio.create_task(start_raid_bot())
    task_bot2 = asyncio.create_task(start_trend_bot())
    await task_bot1
    await task_bot2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```